# How to use button tag outside of form with form.invalid function in template driven form

Tags: angular

```
<form  #documentEditForm="ngForm" id="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onDocSubmit()" >
  <div class="form-group">
                <label for="DOC_NAME">DOC_NAME</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  pInputText
                  id="DOC_NAME"
                  required
                  minlength="4"
                  maxlength="240"
                  [(ngModel)]="bomhdr_doc_value.DOC_NAME"
                  #DOC_NAME="ngModel"
                  name="DOC_NAME"
                  class="form-control"
                  autofocus
                  readonly
                />
</div>
<form/>

<button class="btn-save button primary" form="ngForm 
[disabled]="!documentEditForm.form.valid">SAVE</button>
```

This did not not work. I get:

> error: Property 'documentEditForm' does not exist on type 'BomHeaderTabViewComponent'

Comment: Please add part of your code

Comment: <form #documentEditForm="ngForm" id="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onDocSubmit()" >
.....
</form>
 <button class="btn-save button primary"   form="ngForm" [disabled]="!documentEditForm.form.valid"> 
 SAVE</button>

not worked 
error:Property 'documentEditForm' does not exist on type 'BomHeaderTabViewComponent'.`enter code here`

Comment: @mohanraj Welcome to SO. Please read this introduction and improve your question in order for people to assist you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
In Html:

```
 <form [formGroup]="myF" id="ngForm" novalidate>
      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput required formControlName="name" minlength="4" maxlength="240">
      </mat-form-field>
 </form>            
 <button class="btn-save button primary" [disabled]="!myF.valid">SAVE</button>
```

in TS:

```
  myF = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  })
```

another option:

```
<form id="ngForm">
      <mat-form-field>
         <input [formControl]="myF" matInput required minlength="4"  maxlength="240">
       </mat-form-field>
 </form>
<button class="btn-save button primary" [disabled]="!myF.valid">SAVE</button>
```

TS:

```
  myF = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
```

And finaly with ngmodel:

```
<form id="ngForm">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input #inp ([ngModel])="myF" matInput required minlength="4" maxlength="240">
         </mat-form-field>
        </form>
 <button class="btn-save button primary" [disabled]="myF.length <= 4">SAVE</button>
{{inp.value}}
```

and TS:

```
myF = '';
```

Comment: thank u so much..it works but this is ilike reactive forms model...but i want in template driven form like no validation in .ts file..                                                                                                      ex:      <input type="text" pInputText   id="DOC_NAME"   required  minlength="4"   maxlength="240"   [(ngModel)]="bomhdr_doc_value.DOC_NAME"              #DOC_NAME="ngModel"    name="DOC_NAME"   class="form-control"   autofocus
                    />

Comment: Look now I modify my answer